# A common transparent image path for all images in aspx page and the actual image url in css

Tags: image, logic, transparent

I am giving a common transparent image for all the images in the aspx page and using the css class, the actual image path is set. But the image(which is given in css) is not loading.

I have created the transparent image using MS Paint by opening a new and giving attributes width=1px and height=1px.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ViewFlightItinerary" runat="server" 
    ImageUrl="~/Common/Images/transparent_image.JPG" CssClass="ViewFlightItinerary"/>
```

CSS

```
 .ViewFlightItinerary
      {
         background-image: url(../Images/ViewFlightItinerary.jpg);
         height:150px;
         width:150px;
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site (http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000979.htm) and others claim you cannot create transparent image using Windows Paint. Maybe that's the issue.